# Circular import problems for Python typing

Tags: python, oop, python-typing

### Introduction

I am trying to use a one-to-many relationship in Python but I have some troubles actually implementing because of problems of circular dependencies using Python typing.

I get the following code is a problem, but I spent hours searching for a way of workaround and did not find anything.

### Class Diagram

Let's say I have the following class diagram:
[image]

### What I try to achieve

I am trying to write such a child of Task:

*modules/specific_task.py*

```
from specific_executor import SpecificExecutor
from task import Task

class SpecificTask(Task[SpecificExecutor]):
    def run(self):
        self.my_executor.function_in_specific_executor()
```

Knowing the following `SpecificExecutor`:

```py
from executor import Executor

class SpecificExecutor(Executor):
    def function_in_specific_executor(self):
        pass
```

I need `self.my_executor` to be set to type `SpecificExecutor` to make sure that I have access to functions from `SpecificExecutor`.

### What it would look w/o circular problems

I have thus the following files to implement them:

*modules/executor.py*

```py
from task import Task
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, List

TaskType = TypeVar("TaskType", bound=Task)

class Executor(Generic[TaskType]):
    def __init__(self, tasks: List[TaskType]):
        self.my_tasks = tasks

    def run_function(self):
        pass
```

*modules/task.py*

```py
from executor import Executor
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

ExecutorType = TypeVar("ExecutorType", bound=Executor)

class Task(Generic[ExecutorType]):
    def __init__(self, executor: ExecutorType):
        self.my_executor = executor

    def do_something(self):
        self.my_executor.run_function()
```

### What I did try

- I am aware of the existence of `TYPE_CHECKING` variable but it does not work when using `bound` in `TypeVar` because this is evaluated at running time.
- It would be possible to use `cast(SpecificExecutor, self.executor)` every time I use this variable but this is very verbose and I would prefer to avoid that, because I know that for `SpecificTask`, `self.executor` will always be `SpecificExecutor`.
- I tried to add `from __future__ import annotations` at the beginning of every file but it does not fix circular import issue

Comment: `from __future__ import annotations` so your annotations aren't evaluated at runtime at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but trying to add this line at the beginning of every file does not fix the issue

Comment: *I am aware of the existence of TYPE_CHECKING variable but it does not work when using bound in TypeVar because this is evaluated at running time.* → Why don't you use `if TYPE_CHECKING` to only evaluate it during type checking?

Comment: @mkrieger1, I do use it but when doing `ExecutorType = TypeVar("ExecutorType", bound=Executor)`, with `import Executor` inside `TYPE_CHECKING`, it fails as the row is evaluated at running time, so process files saying `name 'Executor' is not defined`

Comment: Circular imports aside, this will never work properly because it would require [higher-kinded type variables](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/548).

Comment: It's not evaluated at running time if you move it inside `if TYPE_CHECKING`

Comment: If I put `ExecutorType = TypeVar("ExecutorType", bound=Executor)` inside the `if TYPE_CHECKING`, then it is the error `name 'ExecutorType' is not defined` that comes up

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg That was my biggest fear... Any workaround you see to have something that works without being too verbose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle, solving the circular import problem for typing purposes is very simple. Just put one of the imports that would cause a cycle in a [`if TYPE_CHECKING`-block](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING).

In your specific case, you are using the imported class to define an upper bound on the type variable. Trying to pass for example the `Executor` class as an argument would obviously fail at runtime because of the `if TYPE_CHECKING`-block not being executed.

The workaround is to just put the `bound` argument in quotes. The type checker will still know what you are referring to and at runtime Python just doesn't care.

However the bigger problem here is that you have a circular relationship between those generic types `Executor` and `Task` and properly typing this would require [higher-kinded type variables](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/548), which we don't have (yet?).

The best you could do is the following.

**`executor.py`**

```py
from typing import Any, Generic, TypeVar

from .task import Task

T = TypeVar("T", bound=Task[Any])


class Executor(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, tasks: list[T]) -> None:
        self.my_tasks = tasks

    def run_function(self) -> None:
        pass
```

Note the `Task[Any]` in the upper bound for `T`.

**`task.py`**

```py
from typing import Generic, TYPE_CHECKING, TypeVar

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from .executor import Executor

E = TypeVar("E", bound="Executor")  # type: ignore[type-arg]


class Task(Generic[E]):
    def __init__(self, executor: E) -> None:
        self.my_executor = executor

    def do_something(self) -> None:
        self.my_executor.run_function()
```

Note the `type: ignore[type-arg]` directive for the upper bound on `E`. This is just to show an alternative way of dealing with the issue.

**`specific_executor.py`**

```py
from typing import Any, TypeVar

from .executor import Executor
from .task import Task

T = TypeVar("T", bound=Task[Any])


class SpecificExecutor(Executor[T]):
    def function_in_specific_executor(self) -> None:
        pass
```

**`specific_task.py`**

```py
from .specific_executor import SpecificExecutor
from .task import Task


class SpecificTask(Task[SpecificExecutor["SpecificTask"]]):
    def run(self) -> None:
        self.my_executor.function_in_specific_executor()
```

Now if you for example add `reveal_type(self.my_executor)` within that `SpecificTask.run` method, Mypy will tell you that it sees it as being of type `SpecificExecutor[SpecificTask]`, which is what you would expect.

By extension, doing `reveal_type(self.my_executor.my_tasks[0])` would yield you the type `SpecificTask`.

In this setup, `SpecificExecutor` is still generic (just like `Executor`), which seemed like something you wanted. But you could of course apply the same principle of type-checker-only-imports to bind it to `SpecificTask`. Then the latter would of course not need to pass itself as a type argument to `SpecificExecutor` in the "nested" type argument during subclassing.

It would look like this:

**`specific_executor.py`**

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

from .executor import Executor
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from .specific_task import SpecificTask


class SpecificExecutor(Executor[SpecificTask]):
    def function_in_specific_executor(self) -> None:
        reveal_type(self.my_tasks[0])
```

**`specific_task.py`**

```py
from .specific_executor import SpecificExecutor
from .task import Task


class SpecificTask(Task[SpecificExecutor]):
    def run(self) -> None:
        self.my_executor.function_in_specific_executor()
```

Comment: This works like a charm, thank you so much for your complete answer, I guess the main thing I missed was to use quotes around `Executor` when doing the `bound`.